Lee Smooth Manifolds Theorem 6.24 proof
I'm currently reading the book Smooth Manifolds by John M.Lee. There is something unclear to me in the proof of theorem $6.24$, the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem. The proof goes as follows. First, if $M\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ is an $m$-dimensional embedded submanifold then for each $x\in M$ we define $N_xM\subseteq T_x\mathbb{R^n}$ to be the orthogonal complement of $T_xM$ with respect to the standard dot product on $T_x\mathbb{R^n}\cong\mathbb{R^n}$. Then the normal bundle is define as follows:
$NM=\{(x,v)\in\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}: x\in M, v\in N_xM\}$
This is an embedded $n$-dimensional submanifold of $T\mathbb{R^n}\cong\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}$.
And now we define a map $E:NM\to\mathbb{R^n}$ by $E(x,v)=x+v$. So at the beginning of the proof, the author claims that the differential $dE_{(x,0)}$ is bijective at each point of the form $(x,0)\in NM$. To see this, first let $M_0=\{(x,0): x\in M\}\subseteq NM$. The restriction of $E$ to $M_0$ is the natural diffeomorphism $M_0\to M$, and so $dE_{(x,0)}$ maps the subspace $T_{(x,0)}M_0\subseteq T_{(x,0)}NM$ isomorphically to $T_xM$. This part is clear.
But now we also consider the restriction of $E$ to the fiber $\{x\}\times N_xM$. On this fiber $E$ is the affine map $(x,w)\to x+w$. The author claims that it follows that $dE_{(x,0)}$ maps $T_{(x,0)}(\{x\}\times N_xM)\subseteq T_{(x,0)}NM$ isomorphically onto $N_xM$. And this is something I can't understand for hours. Why is the image $N_xM$?
I thought like this: if we look at the map $\{x\}\times\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^n}$ by $(x,w)\to x+w$ then since this is an affine map, it is clear that the differential will just be the identity. But can we claim from this that elements of $T_{(x,0)}(\{x\}\times N_xM)$ are mapped to $N_xM$? I'm not sure about that. I'm probably still not too comfortable with tangent spaces and their identifications. Any help will be appreciated.
